# How to add 3rd party dependencies to an iOS Framework?

Tags: ios, frameworks

I am currently creating an iOS framework, and I don't seem to get the dependencies to 3rd party libs correct.

The end result I want to achieve is to specify in the docs that the people using it should link their binary against my framework and 3rd party `libA` and be done with it (or use cocoapods to define the dependencies), however I can't get this scenario to work when creating my framework.

Right now I have a workspace containing:

- MyFramework
- MyAppThatUsesTheFramework
- Pods Project

in my podfile I have a library `LibA` that I want to use in my framework. How can I build my framework correctly, using that `LibA` without getting compile or link errors? Should I configure my `podfile` somehow so it gets included in the framework too?

I'd rather avoid linking in `LibA` directly in case the person using the lib also wants to use `LibA` in his code for other purposes.

The only thing that works right now is including and linking `LibA` directly in my framework.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your framework static or dynamic? Is `LibA` static or dynamic?

Comment: It's the standard "Cocoa Touch Framework" in iOS.

Comment: `LibA` is a cocoapods dependency, and i use the `use_frameworks!` directive in the podfile

Comment: please provide solution if available.